# Book in which all colors are described in hex

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a list of top 5 or top 10 weirdest sci fi books somewhere around a few years ago from 2018, and one of the books featured was quite strange. I can't remember the title or the author but the book had all colors described in hexadecimal. So a red chair would be described as a #ff0000 chair.

Can anyone provide me the book's title and author please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: when did you read it? when was it published? where did you find it (online/meatspace)? how long is the book? when was it set? what are some details about the plot? what are some details about the characters?

Comment: If you can edit the fact this book is a scifi book, as well as more details about the story that'll help us help you, your question will probably be able to be reopened. As it stands, it is currently unclear and very broad.

Answer (score 21):

That sounds a lot like Jasper Fforde's *Shades of Grey*, though they don't use the #ff0000 designations, at least in my US edition.  Instead, especially in the earlier chapters, they talk about colors (sorry, colours) thusly:

> "We're losing him," breathed Dad, handing back the 35-89-96. "Give me a 116-37-97."

and they'll describe someone as:

> Yellow Beta male (Y: 54.9%, R: 22%), 26 yrs.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if you're thinking of the short story [Plum Pie. Zombie Green. Yellow Bee. Purple Monster](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2276643). from Jen Campbell's recent anthology The Beginning of the World in the Middle of the Night.

In the story the colour codes are used to send secret messages:

> At the next petrol station, I find a stamp crumpled at the bottom of my rucksack. We all scribble a letter on an empty packet of tulip seeds and address it to Lily’s favourite newspaper. We want to place an advert, in the hope that she might see it. We argue over what it should say. I want to send her a secret message in HTML colour codes. #7D0541 #CFECEC, which means ‘Bullet Shell’ and ‘Pale Blue Lily’, to let her know that we are fighting and we hope she’s fighting, too.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was dealing with exactly the same question and hopefully my answer matches yours: The Legend of the 10 Elemental Masters ( https://oddbooks.co.uk/oddbooks/legend-10-elemental-masters )

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can make this a good answer if you [edit] it to include some quotes that demonstrate how it matches the question.